# Create a histogram, ignoring some certain values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

Have to create a histogram, neglecting the values higher than constant

I try this:

```
plt.hist(df[df['avg_speed'] < 1])
plt.show()
```

but it's not working, because of comparison returns the boolean values.
How to repair it?

Comment: Do you mind providing a sample of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you check the types of your dataframe columns
printing df.dtypes is one way of doing it.

**Make sure they integers (int64).**

I tried your code and it works with a simple table.

```
    import pandas as pd

    data = {"avg_speed": [1,2,3,4,5,6]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    table = df[df["avg_speed"] > 1]
    plt.hist(table.avg_speed)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: OK, and what if i must compare float values with 1

Comment: Not a problem, you can compare them if you want or convert all of them to floats using df.astype

Answer (score 0):

```
sub_df = df.loc[df['avg_speed'] <1] 

plt.hist(sub_df)
```